# Force edge direction GraphViz

Tags: graph-theory, graphviz

I'd like draw a diagram like this. 
[image]

But the only diagram I can draw is: 
[image]

I'd like to change the position of the edges among textual, speed and visual to the east side of nodes.

The code I used:

```
digraph {
graph [rankdir = LR]
ranksep=3;
nodesep=0.2;

subgraph cluster0{
     style=invis;
     node [style=invis]
     t0;t1
     edge[style=invis];
     t0->t1
}
node [shape=box]
x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6;x7;x8;x9
node [shape=oval]
visual;textual;speed
{
    t0->x1->x2->x3->x4->x5->x6->x7->x8->x9[style=invis]
    rank=same
    t0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9
}
{
    t1->visual->textual->speed[style=invis]
    rank=same
    t1,visual,textual,speed
}
visual->x1[style=dashed label=0.77]
visual->x2[label=0.42]
visual->x3[label=0.58]
textual->x4[style=dashed label=0.85]
textual->x5[label=0.86]
textual->x6[label=0.84]
speed->x7[style=dashed label=0.57]
speed->x8[label=0.72]
speed->x9[label=0.67]
textual->visual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.46]
speed->visual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.47]
speed->textual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.28]

}
```

How can I force the direction of edge?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the preferred result by using the headport and tailport attribute.

```
textual->visual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.46 headport=se tailport=ne concentrate = true]
speed->visual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.47 headport=se tailport=ne]
speed->textual[dir=both constraint=false label=0.28 headport=se tailport=ne]
```

[image]

As for moving the speed->visual edge into the right side of the screen, it doesn't seem to work so well. The fastest workaround I can think of is to make an invisible node at the east side with the 0.47 label, and have two edges connecting from speed->"invisible node"->textual